# OpenMP with Visual Studio: race condition

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I've recently tried to experiment with OpenMP in Visual Studio to learn how to multi-thread my program.

If I try to execute this code serially:

```
int totalSum = 0;

for(int x=0; x < 100; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        totalSum = totalSum + x + y;
    }
}
```

What I end up with is that **totalSum  = 990000**

When I try to merely add OpenMP functionality by saying:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int x=0; x < 100; x++)
    {

        for(int y=0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            totalSum = totalSum + x + y;
        }
    }
```

I end up with **totalSum  = 491293** or 596865 or 638260 etc...

Clearly what is happening is that race conditions seem to be occurring and depending on which thread accesses totalSum first, the final answer differs.

What am I doing incorrectly? x and y are correctly defined as private variables (since they are created within the parallel region).

What can I do to ensure that I get the same answer when I am multi-threading the program compared to when I am executing it serially?

Comment: Your race conditions is `totalSum `...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to use the `reduction` clause:

```
int totalSum = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:totalSum)  //  reduction
for(int x=0; x < 100; x++)
{

    for(int y=0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        totalSum = totalSum + x + y;
    }
}
```

Read up on the OpenMP reduction clause and then you'll understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks Mysticial. I did read up on reduction, seems like it has a similar function to what a critical region does.

Comment: Kinda of. It does it in a much smarter way than a critical region. What it really does is that it gives each thread a local copy of the total sum. Those are added individually. Then when all the threads are done, the local sums are added up to make the final sum at the end. This avoids the need to a critical region.

Comment: Hey Mystical: I was playing around with the code some more and I noticed that if I changed  totalSum = x + y; and keep the reduction clause in there, I come across another race condition where the OpenMP output doesn't match the serial execution. I just can't figure out why that is happening ... any pointers please?

Comment: That's not a race condition. It's just that you don't understand what a reduction is. The `(+:totalSum)` tells the compiler to keep a private copy of `totalSum` for each thread throughout the loop. Then once the parallel region is done, it sums up all the `totalSums` from all the threads. So think about why this is desirable for the summation case. But meaningless for `totalSum = x + y`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I remove the reduction and merely say #pragma omp parallel for. I still get the race condition ..

Comment: Of course it's a race condition if you remove the reduction. All the threads are writing the same variable!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19329/discussion-between-c0d3rz-and-mysticial)

Comment: @c0d3rz, if you'd like to have the same result for `totalSum = x + y;` as in the serial version, you should declare it `lastprivate` instead. Thus its value outside the `parallel` region would match the value from the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Hristo, that worked. I guess I just need to familiarize myself more with OpenMP intricacies and the different clauses. Thanks again ...